# Compiler optimization breaks multi-threaded code

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, d

After having learnt the hard way that [`shared` variables are currently not guarded by memory barriers](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/faq.html#shared_memory_barriers), I have now encountered another issue. Either I am doing something wrong, or the existing compiler optimization in dmd can break multi-threaded code by re-ordering reads of `shared` variables.

As an example, when I compile an executable with `dmd -O` (full optimization), the compiler happily optimizes away the local variable `o` in this code (where `cas` is the compare-and-swap function from [`core.atomic`](http://www.digimars.com/d/2.0/phobos/core_atomic.html))

```
shared uint cnt;
void atomicInc  ( ) { uint o; do { o = cnt; } while ( !cas( &cnt, o, o + 1 ) );}
```

to something like this (see dis-assembly below):

```
shared uint cnt;
void atomicInc  ( ) { while ( !cas( &cnt, cnt, cnt + 1 ) ) { } }
```

In the "optimized" code `cnt` is read twice from memory, thereby running the risk that another thread has modified `cnt` in between. The optimization basically destroys the compare-and-swap algorithm.

Is this a bug, or is there a correct way to achieve the desired result? The only work-around I have found so far is to implement the code using assembler.

**Full test code and additional details**
For completeness, here is a full test code that shows both issues (no memory-barriers, and the optimization problem). It produces the following output on three different Windows machines for both dmd 2.049 and dmd 2.050 (assuming that Dekker's algorithm doesn't deadlock, which might happen):

```
dmd -O -run optbug.d
CAS   : failed
Dekker: failed
```

And the loop inside `atomicInc` gets compiled to this with full optimization:

```
; cnt is stored at 447C10h
; while ( !cas( &cnt, o, o + 1 ) ) o = cnt;
; 1) prepare call cas( &cnt, o, o + 1 ): &cnt and o go to stack, o+1 to eax
402027: mov    ecx,447C10h         ; ecx = &cnt
40202C: mov    eax,[447C10h]     ; eax = o1 = cnt
402031: inc    eax                 ; eax = o1 + 1 (third parameter)
402032: push   ecx                 ; push &cnt (first parameter)
    ; next instruction pushes current value of cnt onto stack
    ; as second parameter o instead of re-using o1
402033: push   [447C10h]    
402039: call   4020BC              ; 2) call cas    
40203E: xor    al,1                ; 3) test success
402040: jne    402027              ; no success try again
; end of main loop
```

Here is the test code:

```
import core.atomic;
import core.thread;
import std.stdio;

enum loops = 0xFFFF;
shared uint cnt;

/* *****************************************************************************
 Implement atomicOp!("+=")(cnt, 1U); with CAS. The code below doesn't work with
 the "-O" compiler flag because cnt is read twice while calling cas and another
 thread can modify cnt in between.
*/
enum threads = 8;

void atomicInc  ( ) { uint o; do { o = cnt; } while ( !cas( &cnt, o, o + 1 ) );}
void threadFunc ( ) { foreach (i; 0..loops) atomicInc; }

void testCas ( ) {
    cnt = 0;
    auto tgCas = new ThreadGroup;
    foreach (i; 0..threads) tgCas.create(&threadFunc);
    tgCas.joinAll;
    writeln( "CAS   : ", cnt == loops * threads ? "passed" : "failed" );
}

/* *****************************************************************************
 Dekker's algorithm. Fails on ia32 (other than atom) because ia32 can re-order 
 read before write. Most likely fails on many other architectures.
*/
shared bool flag1 = false;
shared bool flag2 = false;
shared bool turn2 = false;   // avoids starvation by executing 1 and 2 in turns

void dekkerInc ( ) {
    flag1 = true;
    while ( flag2 ) if ( turn2 ) {
        flag1 = false; while ( turn2 )  {  /* wait until my turn */ }
        flag1 = true;
    }
    cnt++;                   // shouldn't work without a cast
    turn2 = true; flag1 = false;
}

void dekkerDec ( ) {
    flag2 = true;
    while ( flag1 ) if ( !turn2 ) {
        flag2 = false; while ( !turn2 ) { /* wait until my turn */ }
        flag2 = true;
    }
    cnt--;                   // shouldn't work without a cast
    turn2 = false; flag2 = false;
}

void threadDekkerInc ( ) { foreach (i; 0..loops) dekkerInc; }
void threadDekkerDec ( ) { foreach (i; 0..loops) dekkerDec; }

void testDekker ( ) {
    cnt = 0;
    auto tgDekker = new ThreadGroup;
    tgDekker.create( &threadDekkerInc );
    tgDekker.create( &threadDekkerDec );
    tgDekker.joinAll;
    writeln( "Dekker: ", cnt == 0 ? "passed" : "failed" );
}

/* ************************************************************************** */
void main() {
    testCas;
    testDekker;
}
```

Comment: You should probably ask on the digitalmars.D news group (http://www.digitalmars.com/NewsGroup.html) if this is a known issue or report a bug (http://d.puremagic.com/issues/).

Comment: @Michal: I just saw that you have already asked over there (http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D.bugs&artnum=26308). Thanks!

Comment: Has this been added to bugzilla?

Comment: @Trass3r: I don't know. I stopped following D after we encountered this and a few other issues in the tool chain and libraries. There was a short discussion on the mailing list with one contributor. But after this contributor discovered that his code was fine (IIRC, because he has some `asm` code in his loop which prevents the re-ordering) it died down quickly. The other two issues mentioned (the missing memory barriers around shared and the increment / decrement operators working without a cast) are known. But again I don't know whether they have been added to bugzilla (or are fixed by now).

Comment: @Trass3r: there is now a simple fix that I have posted below as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the issues still seem to exist, [`core.atomic`](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_atomic.html) now exposes `atomicLoad` which enables a relative straightforward workaround. To make the `cas` example work, it suffices to load `cnt` atomically:

```
void atomicInc  ( ) { 
    uint o; 
    do {
         o = atomicLoad(cnt); 
    } while ( !cas( &cnt, o, o + 1 ) );
}
```

Similarly, to make Dekker's algorithm work:

```
// ...
while ( atomicLoad(flag2) ) if ( turn2 ) {
// ...
while ( atomicLoad(flag1) ) if ( !turn2 ) {
// ...
```

For architectures other than ia32 (ignoring string operations and SSE) that can also re-order

- reads relative to reads
- or writes relative to writes
- or writes and reads to the same memory location

additional memory barriers would be required.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: you are right, `do{} while` is better (actually, it is the canonical way in C++). I have amended my answer accordingly. Thanks. [I'd be happy if you could quickly check the edit. My `D` is somewhat rusty.]

Comment: actually the previous version was just wrong (you didn't initialize `o` before the while check)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, code it in assembler. If you skip using the cas() function and just write your entire atomicInt function in assembly,  it's only going to be a few lines of code. Until you do so, you're probably going to be fighting against the compiler's optimizations.

On top of all that, you can use the x86 LOCK INC instruction instead of CAS and you should be able to reduce the function to just a line or two of assembly.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Just one note: I am not really interested in a function to atomically increment. The code is just an example to demonstrate the issue. My actual code is more involved. What surprises me so much with this behaviour is that the `cas` function is basically unusable given the optimization. I also wonder what other optimizations dmd might have in store (e.g., can it move shared variable access past a lock). I somehow feel this cannot be right. I agree with the conclusion though: I probably have to code my original function in assembler. +1

Comment: yeah, and unfortunately, it seems to be an issue with many lower level compilers (C++ suffers from this as well). In his talk on "Lock Free Hash Tables" (http://tinyurl.com/yf53bxl) Dr. Cliff Click basically says that he doesn't consider complex lock free structures fee-sable in C++ due to these issues. I'm not sure I agree, but it's probably harder at least. So basically, in my code, I tend to split off the atomic code either in a separate asm file, or code them completely in asm, optimizers are nice, but sometimes they just get in the way.